# Does this AC axial fan need a capacitor?

Tags: ac, induction-motor

I recently found this old axial AC fan in my collection of old vintage electronic stuffs. Its a Rotron Whisper WR2H1 115V 7W 50/60Hz fan, probably from some sort of server computer or something I guess since it isn't a very large fan. My question is does this fan need any sort of capacitor for starting or it can be directly connected to my 110V outlet? I've not played much with AC motors except one from an old exhaust fan and it had a small capacitor connected to it in parallel, without it I guess the motor would heat up and get damaged. I've attached a few pics of the fan below.
[image: IMG 1]

[image: IMG 2]

[image: IMG 3]

Hope that helps. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not need a capacitor. It can be connected directly to your 110-120 volt outlet. It likely has a shaded-pole motor, so there is not a capacitor inside either.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'll try connecting it to the supply now and see how it goes.